# Firebase Database Design For Language DB Structure

Tags: database, firebase, data-structures, database-design, nosql

I have a question related to firebase database structure / nosql database design. My structure looks like the following:

```
Language
-> Course
--> Lesson
----> Exercise / Vocabulary
```

Every time I finish an exercise I want to save the stats of the solved and not solved vocable into firebase db to keep track at every lesson on how good the user is. But I'm struggling with a good solution which doesn't take to much requests nor odd db design.

So I came up with the idea to keep track of the lesson stats like this:

After finishing a lesson pushing every solved or not solved exercise into user_stats_lessons like this:

```
/user_stats_lessons/{userId}/lessons/{lessonId}/stats/{solved: Int, failed: Int}
```

So I setup a listener on my LessonView for every lesson.

```
ref.child("user_stats_lessons").child(user.uid).child("lessons")
```

So every time a lesson changes I'm iterating through the lessons and find the lesson with the corresponding lesson key to find the stats I'm looking for. But I think it's not the best solution for this problem.

Comment: If you're looping through child nodes to a find a specific one, you're downloading more data than is needed. But without seeing the code that you think is suboptimal, it is hard to say anything more specific than that. For a general introduction to the topic, see [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, I want to know in general what would be a good solution for saving the progress of a user in a node like /user_stats_lessons and would it be better to make nested requests (for relations) instead of saving it in a deeply nested structure? What could be a possible structure for this kind of problem?